# Vue3 - Maska - mask to fullname input

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, mask

Currently I'm using maska as a mask library in my vue project.
Is there anyway to write a mask to a **fullname** input that will accepts any letters and upercase the first letter after an space?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I've just figure it.

```html
<template>
  <VTextField
        label="Full Name"
        prepend-icon="mdi-account-circle-outline"
        v-model="name"
        v-mask:[maskOptions]
  />
</template>
```

```js
import {ref} from 'vue';
import { MaskInputOptions } from 'maska';
const maskOptions = ref({
            postProcess(value: string): string {
                function captilizeFirstLetterAndFirstLettersAfterSpace(input: string): string {
                    return input
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .split(' ')
                        .map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
                        .join(' ');
                }
                return captilizeFirstLetterAndFirstLettersAfterSpace(value);
            },
            mask: '@',
            eager: true,
            tokens: {
                '@': {
                    pattern: /[a-zA-ZÀ-ú ]/,
                    repeated: true,
                },
            },
        } as MaskInputOptions);
const name = ref<string|undefined|null>(null);
```